# This SQL cannot cross a 'year end' boundary

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

This SQL is called by a Smarty File designed to download an .xlsx of the output. It works well for all months EXCEPT the Dec. (end of year) report. **Something is needed to get it to cross the year-end boundary** but I can't figure what. ? Thanks.

```
SELECT user_id, cert_name, from_email, created_at, phone as role, 
        delivery, user_street, user_city, user_state, user_zip, 
        user_country_id, standard_fee, expedited_fee 
FROM support_tickets 
WHERE nature = 2 
AND user_id IS NOT NULL 
AND created_at BETWEEN '2012-12-05 04:00:01' and date(concat_ws('-', @year, @month + 1, 1)) 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use date arithmetic, not string concatenation.

If you try to add `@month+1` when month is 12, you get month 13, not month 1 of the next year. There is no month 13 in calendars currently in use.

For your case I would recommend using the [LAST_DAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) function that is built into MySQL. This returns the last date in the current month of its argument.

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT LAST_DAY('2020-12-05') AS last;
+------------+
| last       |
+------------+
| 2020-12-31 |
+------------+
```

I suspect you want the last day of the same month.

If you really want the first day of the next month, use date arithmetic:

```
mysql> SELECT LAST_DAY('2020-12-05') + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS next;
+------------+
| next       |
+------------+
| 2021-01-01 |
+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, I'll try this.. I forgot to mention that the year and month of this SQL are coming from an HTML Form <select><option>.. how can I incorporate that part since the select has multiple years.

Comment: Sorry, one question per customer. Have a nice day!